# Reading a file into a string buffer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

The following is a simplfied version of code that used to work until recently. I am trying to read a text file into a string buffer using the libc6 read function:

```
import ctypes, os
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno = True)

f=os.open('test.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
if f < 0:
    print 'Cannot open file'

buf = create_string_buffer(10)
buf_ptr = ctypes.addressof(buf)

print libc.read(f, buf_ptr, 5)
e = get_errno()
print str(e) + ': ' + os.strerror(e)
print repr(buf.raw)
```

The output has an error

```
>> -1
>> 14: Bad address
>> '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What is going on, what am I missing? Just to be sure, I coded this in C as well and it works just fine. Any suggestions?

EDIT: It might be worth mentioning that the code this came from reads directly from a drive into a memory aligned buffer. That code worked fine for years and suddenly doesn't anymore.

EDIT 1: OK, I correctly checked the error that `read` throws. It is related to the buffer, but I can't figure out what it is (I don't get it in C and there should be no alignment requirements).

Comment: You're missing the error code in `errno` (at the C level). But what's wrong with `mmap`?

Comment: I modified someone else's script, so I am stuck with using their approach with libc. How do I get the `errno`? If I try `print get_errno()` immediately after calling `libc.read`, I get 0.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the buffer address into a `void_p`? `buf_ptr = void_p(ctypes.addressof(buf))`

Comment: This doesn't work as it is, HOWEVER, it lead to the following observation: If I pass a pointer and not an address (i.e. `ctypes.byref` vs `ctypes.addressof`), this works just fine! So, since this used to work, why the need to change?

Comment: @Ivan, what you're doing is fundamentally wrong if you haven't declared `argtypes`. The default integer argument conversion is *documented* to be a C `int`. Did you read the documentation and tutorial? If not declaring `argtypes` (but you should), simply pass `buf`. Basic C knowledge tells us that an array is passed as a pointer to the first element. ctypes doesn't hold the hand of Python programmers who want to dabble in C without taking the time to learn it. It's actually more demanding because it works at the ABI level.

Comment: As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams suggested, you should use `mmap.mmap`. As far as I can see, you're not stuck with `libc.read`. You can directly access or copy a mapped file as a ctypes array.

Comment: @eryksun Did you actually read my question? I have to use libc.read and I had already coded this in C. The code snippet also used to work in python. So, getting back on track, my question boils down to why `ctypes` has changed its interpretation of `libc.read`. A pointer in C is still just a number, so why is the result of `ctypes.addressof` not passed as such to `libc.read`? It would be very informative if there was an actual description in the documentation of how arguments are actually passed to external libraries.

Comment: If all that matters is that the data read is read from the file directly into the ctypes `buf` array, then you do not need to use `libc.read`.  You don't even need for it to be a copy of the data since a ctypes array can directly wrap a `mmap` mapped file. As to the pointer, I already told you it is documented that the default integer argument conversion is to a C `int`, which is a 32-bit value and completely inappropriate for passing a pointer, and that you should just be passing the `buf` array directly. Give me a second, and I'll give a link into the docs.

Comment: A device file is accessed, so memory mapping might be not be the best choice (not mine anyways, script was modified from someone else's). At runtime, passing a pointer is the same as passing an integer, so I have no idea what you are talking about. The ctypes implementation must be mangling the integer when it thinks it is indeed passing an integer, otherwise the external library doesn't care. Case in point, this code USED TO WORK.

Comment: In the section on [calling functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions), it tells you that " Python integers and Python longs are passed as the platforms default C `int` type, their value is masked to fit into the C type.

Comment: Everything is a "number" in a computer, within a given range. In C you have function prototypes, and in ctypes you *should* be using prototypes to define the argument types and result type instead of depending on default conversions, and very often you *have* to define the prototype, such as with a function `restype` that returns a pointer, since the default C `int` conversion would truncate its value on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: One possibility is (and that'd be new) that there is now a truncation from 64bit to 32bit of the result from `ctypes.addressof`.

Comment: You are confusing compile time with run time execution (in regards to the C functions). An again you are ignoring why it used to work just a few months ago.

Comment: `addressof` doesn't truncate anything. It's passing that address as an argument that truncates the value as a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: If you passed a 64-bit integer value to a C function that declares the argument as a 32-bit `int`, you would see the exact same truncation.